# Can a Javascript Object be created without quotes around the key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [datamaps](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps) charting library and came across this notation for data:

```
var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            HIGH: '#afafaf',
            LOW: '#123456',
            MEDIUM: 'blue',
            UNKNOWN: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            defaultFill: 'green'
        },
        data: {
            IRL: {
                fillKey: 'LOW',
                numberOfThings: 2002
            },
            USA: {
                fillKey: 'MEDIUM',
                numberOfThings: 10381
            }
        }
    });
```

If I want to place an object in the "data" attribute, I cannot - because the country code is not wrapped in quotes.

How do I build data for such scenarios?

[EDIT]
Here's the JSON that I create in a controller and send it back using a REST callout:

```
{"USA":{"value":"15000.0","countryName":"USA"}}
```

I am changing it to the following to match the way the library accepts data:

```
{USA:{fillKey : 'LOW'}}
```

For using JSON.parse(), needs the data to be in a proper JSON format, like:

```
{"USA":{"fillKey" : "LOW"}}
```

(note the absence of quotes around USA)

Currently, I'm using something like this to create the Datamap:

```
var dataForChart = buildDataForChart();// outputs a string "{USA:{fillKey : 'LOW'}}"   
var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            HIGH: '#afafaf',
            LOW: '#123456',
            MEDIUM: 'blue',
            UNKNOWN: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            defaultFill: 'green'
        },
        data: dataForChart
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please, show , how you generate JSON to pass into data attribute. It seems to be a hash,

Comment: If your data is a json string you can simply use `data : JSON.parse( json_string );`. And what do you mean by "because the country code is not wrapped in quotes."

Comment: _How to build this array_ what array you mean? can you explain your problem?

Comment: @user4035: Just added more info

Comment: @tkay I've updated the post with additional data. I'm unable to use  JSON.parse(dataForChart) because the dataForChart isn't in a proper JSON format : {USA:{"blah":"blah"}} isn't in proper format. The proper format would have been : {"USA":{"blah":"blah"}} Hope I made sense !

Comment: @Grundy Oops, I think I've posted this without editing the title. Thanks for spotting that !  I find it strange that the data accepted by this library doesn't use a proper JSON format and I'm guessing there's something I'm missing.

Comment: i'm not quite understand where is problem: server send you json, you can parse it with `JSON.parse`, `options.data` is plain object in your sample, so you can simple pass parsed result

Comment: There was a mistake from my end - I tried building a JSON string that looks like {"USA":{"blah":"blah"}} and it worked. I must've made a mistake earlier when I was building a plain JSON string. As Grundy says, it was straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var options = {
    element: ...,
    fills: ...,
    data: {
        IRL: {
            fillKey: 'LOW',
            numberOfThings: 2002
        },
        USA: {
            fillKey: 'MEDIUM',
            numberOfThings: 10381
        }
    }
}

options.data.CAN = { fillKey: 'HIGH', numberOfThings: 4201 };

var map = new Datamap(options);
```

Comment: that looks like a nice way! The challenge then would be to have an initial dataset for all the countries so that we may later go in and edit it. I'll wait to see if there are any other solutions before I can mark this as the answer. Cheers !